# Clean up img tags in a full html string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a full HTML string.  It looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is a test
     <img width=403 height="302" id="someid1" src="http://mysite.com/images1">
     <img width="456" height=300 src="http://mysite.com/images2" id="someid2">
  </body>
</head>
```

What I would like to do is clean up the source.  I want to remove all widths and heights in the img tags only.  I want to preserve the ID and SRC attributes.

Comment: What's wrong with editing the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex here. Using an html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) would be better..

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach (var img in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img"))
{
    img.Attributes.Remove("width");
    img.Attributes.Remove("height");
}

var newhtml = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```